# Efficient way of flattening a recursive data structure in golang

Tags: arrays, go, data-structures

I have a recursive data structure that can contain a few different type of data:

```
type Data interface{
 // Some methods
}
type Pair struct { // implements Data
  fst Data
  snd Data
}
type Number float64 // implements Data
```

Now I want to flatten a chain of `Pair`s into a `[]Data`. However, the `Data` in the `fst` field should not be flattened, only data in `snd` should be flattened. E.g:

```
chain := Pair{Number(1.0), Pair{Number(2.0), Pair{Number(3.0), nil}}}
chain2 := Pair{Pair{Number(1.0), Number(4.0)}, Pair{Number(2.0), Pair{Number(3.0), nil}}}
```

becomes:

```
data := []Data{Number(1.0), Number(2.0), Number(3.0)}
data2 := []Data{Pair{Number(1.0), Number(4.0)}, Number(2.0), Number(3.0)}
```

My naive approach would be:

```
var data []Data
chain := Pair{Number(1.0), Pair{Number(2.0), Pair{Number(3.0), nil}}}

for chain != nil {
    data = append(data, chain.fst)
    chain = chain.snd
}
```

Is there a more efficient approach that can flatten a data structure like the one in the variable `chain` into an `[]Data` array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function. On the way down, add up the number of pairs, at the bottom, allocate the array, and on the way back up, fill the array from back to front.

If you need to support arbitrary trees, you can add a `size` method to `Data`, and then do another tree traversal to actually fill the array.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, your naive approach doesn't work for `Pair`s nested inside `fst`. If you had `chain := Pair{Pair{Number(1.0), Number(2.0)}, Number{3.0}}`, it would end up as `[]Data{Pair{Number(1.0), Number(2.0)}, Number{3.0}}`. This is an inherently recursive problem, so why not implement it as such?

I suggest adding a `flatten()` method to your interface. `Pair`s can just recursively nest themselves, and `Number`s just return their value.

Here's a fully working example with some minimal testing:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Data interface {
    flatten() []Data
}

type Pair struct {
    fst Data
    snd Data
}

type Number float64

func (p Pair) flatten() []Data {
    res := []Data{}
    if p.fst != nil {
        res = append(res, p.fst.flatten()...)
    }
    if p.snd != nil {
        res = append(res, p.snd.flatten()...)
    }
    return res
}

func (n Number) flatten() []Data {
    return []Data{n}
}

func main() {
    tests := []Data{
        Pair{Number(1.0), Pair{Number(2.0), Pair{Number(3.0), nil}}},
        Pair{Pair{Number(1.0), Number(2.0)}, Number(3.0)},
        Pair{Pair{Pair{Number(1.0), Number(2.0)}, Pair{Number(3.0), Number(4.0)}}, Pair{Pair{Number(5.0), Number(6.0)}, Number(7.0)}},
        Number(1.0),
    }
    for _, t := range tests {
        fmt.Printf("Original: %v\n", t)
        fmt.Printf("Flattened: %v\n", t.flatten())
    }
}
```

(This assumes that the top-level input `Data` is never `nil`).

The code prints:

```
Original: {1 {2 {3 <nil>}}}
Flattened: [1 2 3]
Original: {{1 2} 3}
Flattened: [1 2 3]
Original: {{{1 2} {3 4}} {{5 6} 7}}
Flattened: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
Original: 1
Flattened: [1]
```

Comment: In my case the data in `fst` shouldn't be flattened, only the data in the `snd` field should be. I should have been more clear about that in the question (have updated it now). Not sure what to call that since it's not realy a complete flattening of the datastructure... anyway, what I'm after is a more efficient approach than repeatedly using `append(data, c.fst)`, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, writing a recursive function fits best for this problem. But it's also possible to write a non-recursive version (IMHO recursive version would be more clear):

```
func flatten(d Data) []Data {
    var res []Data

    stack := []Data{d}

    for {
        if len(stack) == 0 {
            break
        }
        switch x := stack[len(stack)-1].(type) {
        case Pair:
            stack[len(stack)-1] = x.snd
            stack = append(stack, x.fst)
        case Number:
            res = append(res, x)
            stack = stack[:len(stack)-1]
        default:
            if x == nil {
                stack = stack[:len(stack)-1]
            } else {
                panic("INVALID TYPE")
            }
        }
    }

    return res
}
```